# How to do browserless testing of an Office UI Fabric form in React

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, office-ui-fabric

I'm trying to do browserless testing with [Enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html) of a form made of Office UI Fabric components in a React application.
Unfortunately I'm having a hard time filling out the value for Dropdown components, since it is composed of several nested span and button elements with unpredictable ids.
Is there any example or recommendation on this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every component in Fabric has a *.test.tsx in their source code. In this case there are a few dozen test cases in [Dropdown.test.tsx](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/Dropdown/Dropdown.test.tsx) at GitHub

Basically, you can use `ReactTestUtils.Simulat.click` to click on that dropdown, and to use normal DOM manipulation to get the second or N elements:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Dropdown label="testgroup" defaultSelectedKeys={['1']} multiSelect id="test" options={DEFAULT_OPTIONS} />,
        container
);
dropdownRoot = container.querySelector('.ms-Dropdown') as HTMLElement;
ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(dropdownRoot);
const secondItemElement = document.querySelectorAll('.ms-Dropdown-item[role="checkbox"]')[1] as HTMLElement;
```